# Chrome Extension Settings page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have this piece of code(thanks to [Shah Abax Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2818274/shah-abaz-khan)), and I wanted to make it a Chrome extension.  I wrote a settings/options page, but it doesn't actually save the settings.  Help?

Javascript:

```
var pretty_fied = false;
var isOn = localStorage.isOn;
var isCapFirst = localStorage.isCapFirst;
var firstLetterPerWord = localStorage.firstLetterPerWord;



function yay() {

    if ($("#on").value == "on") {
        isOn = true;
        localStorage["isOn"] = true;
    }
    else {
        isOn = false;
        localStorage["isOn"] = false;
    }


    if ($("#first").value == "on") {
        isCapFirst = true;
        localStorage["isCapFirst"] = true;
    }
    else {
        isCapFirst = false;
        localStorage["isCapFirst"] = false;
    }


    if ($("#per").value == "on") {
        firstLetterPerWord = true;
        localStorage["firstLetterPerWord"] = true;
    }
    else {
        firstLetterPerWord = false;
        localStorage["firstLetterPerWord"] = false;
    }


};



$('input, textarea').keyup(function () {

    alert(isOn);
    if (isOn) {

        prev = true;

        var value = $(this).val();
        var altText = '';
        for (num = 0; num < value.length; num++) {
            if (num % 2 == 0)
                altText += value[num].toUpperCase();
            else
                altText += value[num].toLowerCase();
        }
        $(this).val(altText);
    }


});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Y.A.Y | Options</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/caps.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <form>

            <label>Enabled: </label>
            <select id="on">
                <option value="on">Yes</option>
                <option value="off">No</option>
            </select>

            </br>

            <label>First Letter:</label>
            <select id="first">
                <option value="on">Capital</option>
                <option value="off">Lowercase</option>
            </select>

            </br>

            <label>Change First Letter of Each </label>
            <select id="per">
                <option value="on">Word</option>
                <option value="off">Sentence</option>
            </select>

            <button id="done" onclick="yay()">Save</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

yay() is supposed to save the settings, but it doesn't.

Comment: You can use HTML5 localStorage if you really want to, but not inline js like the onclick handler. Always look in the devtools console when something is not working: you'll see an error there.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome Extension you shouldn't use a LocalStorage. It's for websites.

Use [Chrome Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) instead like this:

JavaScript:

```
var pretty_fied = false;

var isOn;
var isCapFirst;
var firstLetterPerWord;

getData()

function getData() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get( function ( data ) {
        isOn = data.isOn;
        isCapFirst = data.isCapFirst;
        firstLetterPerWord = data.firstLetterPerWord;
    } )
}

function yay() {
    isOn = $("#on").value == "on";
    isCapFirst = $("#first").value == "on";
    firstLetterPerWord = $("#per").value == "on";

    chrome.storage.sync.set( {
        isOn: isOn,
        isCapFirst: isCapFirst,
        firstLetterPerWord: firstLetterPerWord
    } )
}
```

Comment: There's an error at the line where it says "chrome.storage.sync.get( function ( data ) {".  I've never used Chrome Storage.  Help?